# Function for tic-tac-toe board

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

I am using a function to generate a tic-tac-toe board based on user input:

```
def write_board(size):
    h=[size*[0]]
    board=h*size
    return board
```

This function is utilized in another function to automatically generates moves, i.e it's saved to a variable which is called upon:

```
def game(scen,size):
    move=1
    board=write_board(size)
    win=False
    res=None
    while win==False:
        if move%2==1:
            coordinates=[(x, y) for x, l in enumerate(board) for y, i in enumerate(l) if i == 0]
            if coordinates==[]:
                print("Over")
                return 0
                break
            x,y=random.choice(coordinates)
            board[x][y]=1
```

However, multiple coordinates are ticked for one move. For instance, if the move is (1,4), then the result is:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Instead of just:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

However, if the board is hardcoded for the board variable:

```
    board=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Then result is correct, i.e for coordinate(1,4):

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Hope this explanation is clear enough.
Thanks!

Comment: @Samwise is incorrect about what you want instead, which is `return [[0 for a in range(size)] for a in range(size)]`

Comment: Many thanks!!!
[[0 for a in range(size)] for a in range(size)] solved it